# Perform a command on cluster computers

Tags: hadoop, cluster-computing, hadoop-yarn

I'd like to perform some `bash` command on set of computers of yarn cluster. For example, print last line of each logs:

```
tail -n 1 `ls /data/pagerank/Logs/*`
```

There are too many computers in cluster subset to manually enter to each computer and perform the command. Is there a way to automate the procedure?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use the Parallel SSH tool. You can find more at
https://code.google.com/p/parallel-ssh/

A basic tutorial how to use it can be found at 
 http://noone.org/blog/English/Computer/Debian/CoolTools/SSH/parallel-ssh.html